# How to remove jquery highcharts candlestick display unknown text in series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to remove unknown text format in **highchart** **candlestick**

[image]

This is my error text **ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬â€Ã‚Â**.

My code is

```
              xAxis : {
                    "gridLineWidth": 1,
                    startOfWeek: 2,
                    //min: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day,
                    //pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // interval of 1 day
                    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,


                    plotLines : [{
                        value : plot_start,
                        color : '#3AE6FC',
                        dashStyle : 'solid',
                        width : 7,
                        label : {
                            text : plot_text,
                            rotation: 270,
                            align: 'right',
                            x:-7,
                            y:-0,
                            floating:true,
                            useHTML: true,
                            style : {
                                color:"yellow",
                                font: 'bold 15px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif',
                            },

                        }
                    },],


                    plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
                        from: plot_start,
                        to: data[data.length-1][0],
                        color: '#555555'
                    }],


                },//End x Axis


                rangeSelector : {
                    buttons : [/*{
                        type : 'day',
                        count : daysCount,
                        text : daysCountShow + 'D'
                    },*/],
                    selected : 0,
                    inputEnabled : false
                },

                navigator: {
                    enabled : false,
                },


                series : [{
                    name : (data[data.length-1][5]),
                    type: 'candlestick',
                    data : data,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }],

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            color: '#698587'
                        },
                        marker: {
                            lineColor: '#333'
                        }
                    },
                    boxplot: {
                        fillColor: '#000000'
                    },
                    candlestick: {
                        lineColor: '#ffffff',
                        color: 'red',
                        upColor: '#7BFF00'
                    },
                    errorbar: {
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Use name as 'NIF***'

Comment: And what is include inside `title` ?

Comment: @Zl3n i can't understand..

Comment: @ArunKumar Please show us the whole JS code

Comment: @ArunKumar That means you are using different coding than UTF-8, try <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" / > in your html meta tag

Comment: @Nishith Chaturvedi  Same problem. not working this method..

Comment: style: { fontFamily: '\"Trebuchet MS"\',Verdana, sans-serif', lineHeight: '18px', fontSize: '17px' } try this change as well in font

Comment: Apart of html meta tag, your files should also be encoded in utf8